# Read time out on build application

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I create Android project in Android Studio 3.1.2, I am getting the following errors:

```
read time out
```

and

```
org.gradle.api.resources.resource exception : could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.2/builder-3.1.2.jar'
```

I download this file with browser.

How can I install manually?
How can  I stop downloads for any project and download one time for all project?

**Note**: I am using hot spot shield and then I am creating a project.

Comment: From where you got 3.1.2 reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Gradle issue nothing else , 
Delete your Gradle file and build your project  again .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> Go to build.gradle file which is at same level of your app folder. Inside you will get dependencies section just add

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

as shown in below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to update app level project gradle file.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```